# InvalidCastException with share target on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, .net

I'm experimenting with  Windows 8 "Metro Styled Apps", MVVM Light and want to create a share target - so far so good. But if I'm in the OnShareTargetActivated method and want to add an item to an ObservableCollection I catch an InvalidCastException between class type and COM Object.

> Das COM-Objekt des Typs
>   "System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler"
>   kann nicht in den Klassentyp
>   "System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler"
>   umgewandelt werden. Instanzen von Typen, die COM-Komponenten
>   repräsentieren, können nicht in andere Typen umgewandelt werden, die
>   keine COM-Komponenten repräsentieren. Eine Umwandlung in
>   Schnittstellen ist jedoch möglich, sofern die zugrunde liegende
>   COM-Komponente QueryInterface-Aufrufe für die IID der Schnittstelle
>   unterstützt.

English version:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler' to class type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Now Im a Little bit confused and don't know how to handle this behavior properly.

```cs
MainViewModel main1 = new ViewModelLocator().Main;
MainViewModel main2 = new MainViewModel();
var conversation = new ConversationViewModel();
conversation.Messages.Add(new MessageViewModel { Image = img, Text = "Share" });
main1.Conversations.Add(conversation); // error InvalidCastException 
main2.Conversations.Add(conversation); // no error
```

Where `img` is a newly created BitmapImage

ViewModelLocator

```cs
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UserViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UriViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Stack Trace:

> at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRTDelegate(Object
>   objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)
>      at
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>
>      at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, T item)    at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T
>   item)

Comment: Hope you don't mind. I've added the English version of the same exception message and stack trace to the question. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: The error is about the calling context of the application - the two objects have the same type, but one is a com object(share) and the other a ".net" object(ViewModelLocaltor().Main) - mixim them together results in such problems..

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Has anyone found a resolution?

Comment: It'd help to see how you are creating the img object.

Comment: Would you post the code from your ViewModelLocator class for the "Main" property

Comment: Added the ViewModelLocator code - what I did to solve my Problem is, to store the updates i did in the isolatedstorage and checked this file when the app got the focus again. That solved my problem

Comment: Have you tried this, return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance() as MainViewModel;

Comment: Are your view-models in a portable class library?

Comment: How does your Conversations property declaration look?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicit casting use the "as" conversion, it sounds like the instance returned by the service locator is not a `MainViewModel` object, change that line to

```
return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance() as MainViewModel;
```

It may behave differently, if the instance is not a `MainviewModel` then it will return `null`, this will help you debug why the instance returned `null` from the service locator.