# InvalidCastException on ShareTarget [Windows 10 UWP]

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have app that supports ShareTarget to upload files to cloud. Everything works great when I my app is closed (and I mean closed - not hibernated or something like this) - I choose share photo and everyting goes as expected. But when I open the app, then exit (app stays hibernated in memory) and try to share something on line

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

I get

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Message "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' to class type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface."
```

Then my app closes completely and second try is success. Whole onShareTarget code:

```
protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        return;
    AppShell shell = Window.Current.Content as AppShell;
    if (shell == null)
        shell = new AppShell();
    Window.Current.Content = shell;
    shell.AppFrame.Navigate(typeof(ChooseFolderPage), args.ShareOperation);
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Tested your code, it works fine by my side, at least there is no problem with your posted code. I think your problem is possible with your AppShell.xaml.cs code, could you please post the code of `PropertyChangedEventHandler`? And there is a similar question [InvalidCastException with share target on Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326069/invalidcastexception-with-share-target-on-windows-8), you can check if the answer there works with you.

Comment: Just wondering - are you using Caliburn.Micro framework?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' to class type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not